# How to scale test set based on the mean and std from train set in python?

Tags: python, scale, normalization, standardized

I read an answer to explain "[Why feature scaling only to training set?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/319514/why-feature-scaling-only-to-training-set)"
"
and the answer says "Standardize any test set using the training set means and standard deviations"

Therefore, I try to fix my previous incorrect operation. However, I check the [official document](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler.html?highlight=scaler#sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler) of StandardScaler(), it cannot support to scale with given mean and std. like this:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler(mean = train_x.mean(), var_x = train.std())
sc.fit(test_x)

# this code is incorrect, but what is the correct code?
```

So, my question is how to scale the test set based on the mean and std from the train set in python.

Comment: It will scale default as the with_mean and with _std are given True. So when you pass the test_x, it will automatically calculate the mean and std then process the scaling. Your code should be like this. sc= StandardScaler() sc.fit(test_x)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the official documents,

> with_mean bool, default=True If True, center the data before scaling.
> This does not work (and will raise an exception) when attempted on
> sparse matrices, because centering them entails building a dense
> matrix which in common use cases is likely to be too large to fit in
> memory.
>
> with_std bool, default=True If True, scale the data to unit variance
> (or equivalently, unit standard deviation).

So you can just simply do it like this.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(test_x)
```

StandardScaler() only takes with_mean and with_std as boolean that means the value of these either True or False.

Comment: So, if I want to use train_x to scale test_x, I shoud: sc = StandardScaler()
sc.fit(train_x) then sc.transform(test_x)